# Django Rest Framework - how to get only one field from related models set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following models:

```py
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class BusStop(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
```

Now using Django Rest Framework, I would like to create serializer that will return City details along with the list of all BusStops in the city - but I want the list to be only strings with BusStop names, like this:

```
{
  "id": 1
  "name": "City"
  "last_update": "2019-09-19T22:13:54.851363Z"
  "bus_stops": [
    "stop1",
    "stop2",
    "stop3"
  ]
}
```

What I've tried so far is following serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class BusStopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BusStop
        fields = ('name', )


class CityDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    busstop_set = BusStopSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'last_update', 'busstop_set')
```

But this creates list of objects with 'name' in them. So, how can I create a list with only `BusStop` names (as strings) in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringRelatedField, as recommended by wfehr, will only work as long as the `__str__` method of BusStop only returns the name. An alternative is to use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) which allows you to specify a particular field from the related model, and has no dependency on `__str__`.

```
bus_stops = SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='name')
```

Comment: That is great! I think I also have to add `related_name` to `city` field in my `BusStop`  model: `city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='bus_stops', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` (so that bus_stops name is recognized correctly)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the extra `BusStopSerializer` you could use a [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield):

```
# models.py
class BusStop(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# serializers.py
class CityDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bus_stops = StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'last_update', 'bus_stops')
```